# python request: how to loop the request.post in for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, python-requests

I'm trying to loop the `request.post` request in python to post the value to the server, so I'm using the `for` loop. (The code name is `temp-hum-log2.py`)

```
with open('Data_IoT.Input.swift01.5.json', 'r') as readfile:
    data1 = json.load(readfile)
for info1 in data1:
    with open('a.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(info1, outfile)
    execfile('ECIES_enc.py')
    with open('b.json', 'r') as editfile:
        data1 = json.load(editfile)
    ecc = data1["ecc"]
    privateKey = data1["Private key"]
    cipher = data1["cipher"]
    otp = data1["otp"]
    payload2 = {"cipher": cipher}
    with open('b.json', 'w') as editfile:
        json.dump(payload2, editfile)
    with open('b.json', 'r') as myfile:
        data2=myfile.read()
    payloadenc = json.loads(data2)
    params2 = {"privateKey" : privateKey, "ecc" : ecc, "otp" :otp}
    r = requests.post(url, json=payloadenc, params = params2, timeout = 10)
```

At first when I didn't add the `timeout` in `request.post`, the loop didn't continue because it got stuck at the post request and didn't continue to the next line/loop. So I added the `timeout` into it, but instead, the timeout just ended the code process entirely

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp-hum-log2.py", line 102, in <module>
    r = requests.post(url, json=payloadenc, params = params2, timeout = 10)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='35.247.186.59', port=3340): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

for additional information, this is the `post` method in the server side with Express in Node.js

```
app.post('/temperature_humidity', function(req, res) {
    startTime = new Date();
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    temp_hum_json_enc = req.body;
        privateKey = req.query.privateKey;
        ecc = req.query.ecc;
        otp1 = req.query.otp;
        temp_hum_json_enc.privateKey = privateKey;
        temp_hum_json_enc.ecc = ecc;
        temp_hum_json_enc.otp = otp1;
    const data_enc = JSON.stringify(temp_hum_json_enc);
        const data_otp = JSON.stringify(otp1);
    fs.writeFile('b.json', data_enc, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Saved!');
    });
    fs.writeFile('otpauth.json', data_otp, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
    startTime = new Date();
});
```

What can I do to make the code loop the post request properly?

Comment: Your loop broke because of an exception. You need to handle the exception to so that the loop continues. Use a try - catch block around your request.post statement.

Comment: Maybe it’s deliberate but it looks very odd when inside your loop `for info1 in data1:` you overwrite the value of `data1` with `data1 = json.load(editfile)`

Comment: @AmalTs Thank you! it works! For Barny Yes, I admit I did a mistake on that part. I'll fix it